# Fetch subkeys from a hash in redis

Tags: hash, redis

I have a hash in Redis that has two subkeys and corresponding values as:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall hash-key
1) "sub-key1"
2) "value1"
3) "sub-key2"
4) "value2"
```

How can I fetch only the **subkeys** from the hash i.e "sub-key1" , "sub-key2"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use HKEYS command. see example below:

```
redis> HSET myhash field1 "Hello"
(integer) 1
redis> HSET myhash field2 "World"
(integer) 1
redis> HKEYS myhash
1) "field1"
2) "field2"
```

**Array reply: list of fields in the hash, or an empty list when key does not exist.**

Answer (score 2):

You want HKEYS: http://redis.io/commands/hkeys

"HKEYS hash" returns an array of the fields within the hash.